# Django migrate foreignkey with int index set to 10 digits not 11

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a legacy database with int index set to 10 digits. I need Django migrations to create my forigen keys to int(10) not int(11)

By default Django Forigenkey sets int(11) and when try to make the ForigenKeys in Mysql give the error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1005, 'Can\'t create table `test_table`.`#sql-169_1ec` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")')
```

I try to use "validators=[MaxValueValidator(9999999999)]" in model, it transforms the migration to:

```
    field=models.ForeignKey(null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='clients.Customer', validators=[django.core.validators.MaxValueValidator(9999999999)]),
```

But when django migrations create the integer-field it creates with int(11)

Any clue how I can modify the length of int?

My model:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    ... (BUNCH OF FIELDS HERE)....
    django_user = models.ManyToManyField(User, through= 'CustomerUser')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'customers'

class CustomerUser(models.Model):

    ROL_USUARIO = (
        ('T', 'Tecnico'),
        ('G', 'Gerente'),
        ('E', 'Emplead'),
    )

    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null= True, validators=[MaxValueValidator(9999999999)])
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, null= True)
    rol = models.CharField(choices=ROL_USUARIO, max_length = 1, null= True, default='')
```

The migrations:

```
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='CustomerUser',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('rol', models.CharField(choices=[('T', 'Tecnico'), ('G', 'Gerente'), ('E', 'Emplead')], default='', max_length=1, null=True)),
            **intentionally skipped**
            #('cliente', models.ForeignKey(null=True,on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.DO_NOTHING, to='clients.Customer')),
            #('usuario', models.ForeignKey(null=True,on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.DO_NOTHING, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
        ],
    ),



migrations.AddField(
            model_name='customeruser',
            name='cliente',
            field=models.ForeignKey(null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='clients.Customer', validators=[django.core.validators.MaxValueValidator(9999999999)]),
        ),
```

**The last stament raise the error: "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"**

Comment: How does your Model & migrations look?

Answer (score 2):

You have one possible option to create forigenKey with `int(10)`. by  editing empty migration file.

First create empty migration file with

```
python manage.py makemigrations --empty myapp
```

Then edit `operations = []` to excute rawsql with forigenKey int(10)
your new migrations file:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('myapp', '0009_auto_20160623_xxxxx'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL("ALTER TABLE myapp_table MODIFY field_id int(10);")
    ]
```

[RunSQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/migration-operations/#runsql) requires [sqlparse](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlparse)

Comment: I can't do the ALTER TABLE, the script rise the error on creation of the field, but I can append the field with RunSQL and make the relation by hand. I try.